# Type is not visible error when deploying a Salesforce Function

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, salesforce-functions

I recently got access to Salesforce Functions and I am trying to use the `GenericFunctionInvoker.cls` class from the [functions-recipes](https://github.com/trailheadapps/functions-recipes/blob/main/force-app/main/default/classes/GenericFunctionInvoker.cls) repository. `FunctionController.cls` looks like this:

```
public with sharing class FunctionController {
  @AuraEnabled
  public static String invoke(String functionName, String payload) {
    functions.Function function = functions.Function.get(functionName);
    functions.FunctionInvocation invocation = function.invoke(payload);

    if (invocation.getStatus() == functions.FunctionInvocationStatus.ERROR) {
      throw new CalloutException(
        (invocation.getError() != null
          ? invocation.getError().getMessage()
          : 'UNKNOWN')
      );
    }

    String response = invocation.getResponse();
    return response;
  }
}
```

I renamed it to be `FunctionController` but it is really the same.

The definition file `FunctionController.cls-meta.xml` looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ApexClass xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
    <status>Active</status>
</ApexClass>
```

Then from my LWC component I do:

```js
import { LightningElement, api } from "lwc";
import invoke from "@salesforce/apex/FunctionController.invoke";

export default class FunctionTrigger extends LightningElement {
  @api functionName = "hello";
  result;

  handleTrigger(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    (async () => {
      await invoke({
        functionName: `hello.${this.functionName}`,
        payload: `{"body": "Hello"}`
      })
        .then((result) => {
          console.log(JSON.parse(result));
          return true;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          return false;
        });
    })();
  }
}
```

For some reason when I try to push this code to the scratch Org with:

```bash
sfdx force:source:push -u scratch
```

I get this error:

```bash
TYPE   PROJECT PATH                                           PROBLEM
─────  ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────  ──────────────────────────────────────────────
Error  force-app/main/default/classes/FunctionController.cls  Type is not visible: functions.Function (4:5)
Error  force-app/main/default/classes/FunctionController.cls  Type is not visible: functions.Function (5:47)
ERROR running force:source:push:  Push failed.
```

I am using `public with sharing` in the class so I don't know what is going on.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: `public with sharing` shouldn't be a factor in this error, are you sure the org you're pushing to has functions enabled?

Comment: Yes, I also enabled Functions from setup with all toggles on, and Dev Hub also all toggled on. I will add that to the question as well. That was my first idea, but it wasn't the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Try setting your Apex class API version to 53: `<apiVersion>53.0</apiVersion>`

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you, but I dont think I can mark your comment as correct answer, until you post that as an answer.

Comment: I added an answer with all of the relevant details for anyone else that comes across this Q&A.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Salesforce Functions only recently became generally available through the Winter '22 release (API version 53). In order for the [`functions` namespace](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_namespace_functions.htm) to be available the Apex class needs to be running on API version 53 or higher.

## FunctionController.cls-meta.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ApexClass xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>53.0</apiVersion>
    <status>Active</status>
</ApexClass>
```